# Скрол, когда он не нужен

Tags: jquery

Имеется такой скрипт

```
$('.subscribe-close').on('click', function(event) {        
        $('.subscribe').slideToggle('hide');
        $body.removeClass('subscribe-fullscreen');
    });

    $('.subscribe-open a').on('click', function(event) { 
        $body.addClass('subscribe-fullscreen');
        $('.subscribe').slideToggle('show');

    });
```

он открывает снизу вверх окошко с формой подписки и закрывает. Так вот при открытии окна, еще до того как оно полностью откроется происходит скроллинг body вверх, хотя сама кнопка открытия находится над футером. Мне нужно чтобы скроллинга не было, как можно это провернуть? Добавлять к body overflow и position пробовал. Не получается

Answer (score 0):

Вставил `event.preventDefault();`. Помогло